# How do i remove an unnecessary whitespace at top of my web page?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs as you can see below. I want to create 5 px `margin-top` between the two. However `margin-top` of inner div cause unnecessary margin on the top of outer div, and hence cause unnecessary margin at top of the page.
Adding border property to outer div solve the problem and i can also fix it by other hacks like posioning and padding to outer div. However i am curious to know what is causing this problem ?

```
 <div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

  </div> 
 </div>
```

and here is the Css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

.outer{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:black;
}

.inner{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:5px;
  background:red;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to make the display of the outer div inline-block.

```
display: inline-block;
```

cause from what I understand is two display block inside each other with behaving the same if one has margin the other will have and you will no notice that

```css
 html {
      margin: 0;
    }

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      outline: 0;
      font-size: 100%;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      background: transparent;
    }

    .outer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      background: black;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .inner {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      background: red;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>StackOverFlow &#127831;</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the inner div is in the very beginning of outer. One trick would be adding `padding-top` to outer div:

```
.outer{
  /* other stuff */
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.inner{
  /* other stuff */
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

or put all the `5px` in `padding-top`

```
.outer{
  /* other stuff */
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Or you may use another element before the inner div, for example `hr`

```
<div class="outer">
  <hr>
  <div class="inner">

  </div> 
</div>
```

But the best trick is (as Mohammad said) make the outer div `inline-block`.

```
.outer{
  /* other stuff */
  display: inline-block;
}
```